# complex command within a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that among other things runs a shell command several times. This command doesn't handle exit codes very well and I need to know if the process ended successfully or not. 
So what I was thinking is to analyze the **stderr** to find out the word **error** (using grep). I know this is not the best thing to do, I'm working on it.... 
Anyway, the only way I can imagine is to put the **stderr** of that program in a variable and then use grep to well, "grep" it and throw it to another variable. Then I can see if that variable is valorized, meaning that there was an error, and do my work.
The qustion is: how can I do this ?
I don't really want to run the program **inside** a variable, because it has got a lot of arguments (with special characters such as backslash, quotes, doublequotes...) and it's a memory and I/O intensive program. 
Awaiting your reply, thanks.

Comment: Any issue with command1 && command2; echo $?

Comment: do you need the stdout?

Comment: what exactly you want @Omar, the complete error msg or just want to check if script or command executed successfully.

Comment: @almasshaikh yes, as I wrote that command does not valorize the exit code, meaning I can't just look for $? ... although I would have done !

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no, I don't really need it, that's only because THERE there is the error that I need to parse.

Comment: @AmitKumar that's it man, I'm just looking to find the word ERROR, meaning something gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the stderr of that command to a temporary file and check if the word "error" is present in that file.

```
mycommand 2> /tmp/temp.txt
grep error /tmp/temp.txt
```

Comment: most of the shell command does not print string "error" in error message.
Thus searching error in stderr doesn't work actually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jdamian, this was my answer too, in the end. 
I asked my principal if I can write a temp file and it allowed, so this is the end result:

```
... script 
command to be launched -argument -other "argument" -other "other" argument 2>&1 | tee $TEMPFILE
ERRORCODE=( `grep -i error "$TEMPFILE" `)
if [ -z $ERRORCODE ] ;
    then
    some actions ....
```

I didn't tested this yet because I got some other scripts involved that I need to write before. 
What I'm trying to do is:

- run the command, having its stderr redirected to stdout;
- using tee, have the above result printed on screen and also to the temp file;
- have grep to store the string error found on the temp file (if any) in a variable called ERRORCODE;
- if that variable is populated (which mean if it has been created by grep), then the script stops, quitting with status 1, else it contiunes.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the standard output:

```
if mycommand 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q error; then
   echo an error occurred
fi
```